# Ora-01000 - maximum open cursors exceeded error

Tags: database, delphi, oracle10g, cursor

I am receiving the following error message within my Delphi/Oracle application "ora-01000 - maximum open cursors exceeded". The code is as follows:

```
begin
  for i := 0 to 150 do 
  begin

    with myADOQuery do
    begin
      SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM SOMETABLE';
      ExecSQL; -- from looking at V$OPEN_CURSOR a new cursor is added on each iteration for the session
      Close; -- thought this would close the cursor but doesn't
    end;

  end;

end;
```

I'm aware I can resolve the problem by simply increasing the number of OPEN_CURSORS parameters, however, I would rather find a solution whereby the cursor is closed after the query is executed. Any ideas?

Delphi 2006 BDS
Oracle 10g

Comment: What version of 10g are you using **exactly**? I mean, what patchset is applied and what patch number, if any?

Comment: Also, have some of those table triggers?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that your *real* SQL is based on the current value of `i`, so that the SQL is different for each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Read Oracle Support documents ID 76684.1 and ID 2055810.6. I do not use ADO, but you may have to find a way to tell it how to configure Oracle not to cache statements.
- The default max_cursor value is usually too low, is usually better to increase it, it will made Oracle use a little more memory but on actual machine it is rarely an issue.
- To delete a whole table TRUNCATE may be better than DELETE, unless you have to rely on DELETE behaviour (i.e. firing triggers).

Comment: Thanks for your help on this issue. I changed the SQL to TRUNCATE the table and everything is now working perfectly (i.e. no cursor caching).

Comment: Be aware that TRUNCATE can't be rolled back, and there are also other things to take care of - read carefully the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/node/758). I'm not Oracle user, but as it seems there is some cursor cache and as they say "The best advice for tuning OPEN_CURSORS is not to tune it. Set it high enough that you won't have to worry about it." So I would say even if the Close command closes the cursor it still remains in the cache. There are also some tips, how to check your current situation.

Answer (score 1):

try using the [`TADOCommand`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOCommand) component instead.

> TADOCommand is most often used for
>   executing data definition language
>   (DDL) SQL commands or to execute a
>   stored procedure that does not return
>   a result set.

or using directly the [`TADOConnection.Execute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOConnection.Execute) function

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you omit the Close?

Comment: Do you need to do an explicit Commit perhaps?

Comment: The code above is executed within a transaction. I'd like it to commit  upon the user confirming to post changes.